# expect spawn command: Escaping newline (\n) in string

Tags: linux, shell, shell-script, expect

I am trying to use expect to interact with the MATLAB console. Currently I have:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f


spawn {*}/usr/bin/run.sh matlab -r "fprintf(1, \"The identifier was:%s\\\\n\", \"hello\")"

expect {
    "The identifier is hello" {
        return
    }
    timeout {
        exit 7
    } eof {
        return
    }
}
```

but this gives the error:

```
./create_meta_file.exp 
spawn /usr/bin/run.sh matlab -r fprintf(1, "The identifier was:%s\\n", "hello")

MATLAB is selecting SOFTWARE OPENGL rendering.
                   < M A T L A B (R) >
                                                                      Copyright 1984-2022 The MathWorks, Inc.
                                                                 R2022a Update 2 (9.12.0.1956245) 64-bit (glnxa64)
                                                                                   May 11, 2022

 
To get started, type doc.
For product information, visit www.mathworks.com.
 
 fprintf(1, "The identifier was:%s
            |
Error: String is not terminated properly.
```

If I use `\n`, `\\n` or  `\\\n` instead of `\\\\n` in the expect script I get:

```
spawn /usr/bin/run.sh matlab -r fprintf(1, "The identifier was:%s
", "hello")
MATLAB is selecting SOFTWARE OPENGL rendering.
/usr/local/bin/matlab: 1: eval: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
```

Any pointer would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This *should* work:

```
spawn /usr/bin/run.sh matlab -r "fprintf(1, \"The identifier was:%s\\n\", \"hello\")"
# .................................................................^^
```

Although I'd suggest using Tcl's non-interpolating quotes to simplify:

```
spawn /usr/bin/run.sh matlab -r {fprintf(1, "The identifier was:%s\n", "hello")}
# ..............................^..............................................^
```

The leading `{*}` is not needed here: it only applies to "/usr/bin/run.sh" which does not need to be expanded into separate words.